# Display a message using NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

```
NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                target:self
                              selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                              userInfo:nil
                               repeats:NO];
```

How can I use for display the message "your time is over" after 5 min?

Comment: what kind of message you want to show ?? you can show alert or action sheet if you want. what else is your requirement

Answer (score -1):

In below code, Instead 5.0 you can put your time in second

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)targetMethod {
     //enter code here to execute...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion